# Structing your programm with ADT's and type classes

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell and I think I understood the concepts of ADT's and type classes but I am still a little bit confused.

I tried to create a small game and I started to layout the data structures.

Now I started with

```
data Consumable = Food
                | Water
                | Potion

data Equipment = Weapon
               | Shield
```

Both `Consumable` and `Equipment` have a relation, both are Items but I am not sure how I should express this in haskell.

I thought maybe I should make a type class called Item like

```
Class Item where
  use ::
```

and then make consumable and equipment both instances of Item. Or I could express it like

```
data Item = OneTimeUseable Consumable
          | Equipable Equipment
```

It feels like that haskell is much more expressive than other languages that I learned and I have some trouble designing my application.

Any tips / guidelines that you can give me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My rule of thumb is to design your program as though typeclasses don't exist.  If you later come across an abstraction that really needs a typeclass to avoid boilerplate then go ahead and add it.

Comment: Any particular reason or experience for making this a rule of thumb?

Comment: What it all comes down to is that classes are not first class.  You can't pass them around and perform operations on them in the same way that you can functions and values.  I would almost always prefer to have `f :: CDict -> Result` than `f :: Class C => Result`.  It's much harder to start with the former and produce the latter than vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

You could just keeping going with the union idea.

```
data Item = Consume Consumable | Equip Equipment
```

I would stay away from making your own type class.  These are usually used for things that have laws, like monad, functor, applicative.

You could also start to think about which think actually does and use a data type that has functions that has functions as members.

```
data Consumable = Consumable
   {
      -- what happens to the player when he consumes said item
     consume   :: Player -> Player
     -- could this player sell this item and get more money
   , sell      :: Player -> Player
   }
```

Comment: That is really interesting, I didn't even think about putting functions in a data type. Seems really nifty.